# Jest + React: Reset location.href before each test

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, navigation, location-href

I've got a React component that takes into account URL params and then makes some fetches taking into account that param. By default, if no param is set, it uses a default value.

The issue is that Jest seems not to reset the `href` property after each test, so if the previous test navigates to `my-url?some=param`, the next test will have still that `href` set.

This means that after changing that `href` from interacting with the component in the tests, the next test will have the previous value. A side effect from this is that **I cannot test the default value if the param is not set**, because it will be always set by the previous test.

### What I've tried

```
  beforeEach(() => {
    window.location.assign('');
  });
```

Throws error `Not implemented: navigation (except hash changes)`.

```
  beforeEach(() => {
    window.location.href = '';
  });
```

Throws error `Not implemented: navigation (except hash changes)`.

```
  beforeEach(() => {
    Object.defineProperty(window, 'location', {
      value: {
        href: ''
      }
    });
  });
```

Throws error `Cannot redefine property 'location'`.

In all of these cases, it does not matter if it's an empty string `''` or a correct URL like `http://localhost`.

### The question

**Is there some way to reset the `href` property before each test?** I don't mean to mock it: it should work as it's default behaviour, but just reset it before each test.

Shouldn't that be the default behavior for Jest? What's the use in cleaning up the DOM automatically but leaving the `href` with the value from previous test?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like these are not implemented in JSDOM.

You need to mock it anyway. You can try sth like this:

```js
const mockHref = jest.fn();
Object.defineProperty(window, 'location', {
  value: {
    get href() {
      return mockHref();
    },
  },
});

describe('it should work', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    mockHref.mockReturnValue('empty');
  })

  it('should work', () => {
    expect(window.location.href).toEqual('empty')
  })
})
```

Comment: Same issue: `Error: Not implemented: navigation (except hash changes)`.

Comment: In the test itself or in tested code? For me this "test" passes.

Comment: I haven't tested the new code of your edited answer. Let me try when I've got some time to see if it works this way and I'll get back with the results! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Yes you should add

```
beforeEach(() => {
  Object.defineProperty(window, 'location', {
      writable: true,
      value: {
        href: ${yourUrl},
      },
   });
});
```

The `writable:true` should make it possible to reset the url back to yourUrl before every test case.